# can meta function generate declaration according to the variadic params

Tags: c++

I have a function table which contains functions defined somewhere, all the functions may have different param count but have the same param type(that's `var`); the functions will be called by a delegator named `caller`,it gets the function address by a name.

I could not directly forward the args of caller to the function ptr and want to covert them all to `var`,because the miss-type params may be corrupt the stack.

for example, if the original function is int(*)(int,int),but call it using (double,double) may be undefined.

I wonder how to define type to declare a function proto from Args...,for example,
caller(int,int)==>ftype::type will be int(*)(var,var);
caller(char)==>ftype::type will be int(*)(var)...etc.

```
template<typename...A)
struct ftype{
using type=????//todo
};

class var{
public:
var(int);
var(double);
var(bool);
var(char)
var(unsigned);
var(char*);
var(const char*);
};

using voidfptr= void(*)();

extern std::map<string,voidfptr> g_f_tables;

template<typename...Arg>
int caller(std::string& name,Arg&&...args)
{
    using fptr= ftype<args..>::type;
    voidfptr = g_f_tables[name];
    auto _f = (ftpr)(g_fptr);
    if(_f) throw;

    _f(std::forward<Arg>(args...));
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    caller(1,2,3;
    caller(1,2);
     
    return 0;
}
```